# Load a not mapped attribute with EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I try to load an entity with EF Core by calling a stored procedure.
The entity is mapped to a table by fluent mapping which does not contain all columns which are selected by the stored procedure.

The selected fields which do not exist as table columns are ignored in the entity configuration like this:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerLocationEntity>().Ignore(c => c.Latitude);
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerLocationEntity>().Ignore(c => c.Longitude);
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerLocationEntity>().Ignore(c => c.Radius);
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerLocationEntity>().Ignore(c => c.Distance);
```

The stored procedure is called like this:

```
await SalesContext.CustomerLocation
            .FromSql("GetCustomersByLocation @latitude={0}, @longitude={1}, @radius={2}", lat,
                lon, radius)
            .ToListAsync();
```

When the query is executed the ignored columns are not mapped to the entity. Is there any possibility to map the ignored fields to the entity when calling a stored procedure or do I have to create another entity for the stored procedure or something like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use the ignore method of fluent api on column, it will not create that column in sql server (Ignores it).
Your stored procedure result will give you come some columns based on your created query
and these column names must match the property names on your entity.
For example your procedure gives you a table with these columns and also matched data types in sql server and your class:

1. Latitude
2. Longitude
3. Radius
4. Distance

Then you should create a class for your procedure:

```
public class LocationProcedure {
   public string Latitude {get;set;}
   public string Longitude {get;set;}
   public string Radius {get;set;}
   public string Distance {get;set;}
}
```

and also add a dbset of this type to your dbContext with `[NotMapped]` Attribute:

```
[NotMapped]
public DbSet<LocationProcedure> CustomerLocation {get; set:}
```

The attribute tells that this should not be a table in database.

Finally you can use your procedure with the new dbset `CustomerLocation` and then it will map the results to *LocationProcedure* class.

```
await SalesContext.CustomerLocation
            .FromSql("GetCustomersByLocation @latitude={0}, @longitude={1}, @radius={2}", lat,
                lon, radius)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: You made my day! This is not the final solution for me but you brought me on the right way. Since the new entity has a composite key, I needed to declare the key by fluent mapping without binding the entity to a table and the mapping works.

Comment: also Ef needs every dbset to have one column named Id or another primary key. otherwise it throws an exception for that.

Comment: Using `DbSet` with `[NotMapped]` attribute doesn't ignore creation appropriate table in database after applying migration

Comment: Yes, `[NotMapped]` should decorate the `LocationProcedure` class, not the `DbSet`.

Comment: what if my selecting columns in sql in dynamically build? Then iam not getting value to my Notmapped field

Comment: @AmeerPappay What do you mean dynamically? dynamic properties every time?

Comment: I am creating a SQL query string and it's having select columns dynamic in each case. So I have created a c# model with all the fields and gave then NotMapped attribute. But when I query the values are not assigned to it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63177779/notmapped-field-not-get-assigned-by-values-on-procedure-calling-in-net-core/63178438#63178438