# NotMapped Field not get assigned by values on procedure calling in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-core

I have a model of type `DbQuery` in my context for executing a stored procedure in it.

```
public class DynamicClass
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string TitleArabic { get; set; }
    public int? SeasonNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Query:

```
SELECT ItemId, Title, TitleArabic, SeasonNumber 
FROM dynamicclass
```

```
List<DynamicClass> Result = context.DynamicClass.FromSql("SELECT ItemId,Title,TitleArabic,SeasonNumber From dynamicclass").ToList();
```

The query is working fine but the `NotMapped` fields are not getting values while executing the query.

My query may or may not contain `Title` and `TitleArabic` and that is why I have assigned `NotMapped` annotation to these fields.

If I removed all the `NotMapped` annotations and query results doesn't contain all the columns I have specified in the model, then I get an error

> The required column 'Title' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation

How can I solve this or is there any better idea?

Comment: Maybe you can check the columns in the database first.I hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42455279/how-to-get-column-name-and-corresponding-database-type-from-dbcontext-in-entity) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The [NotMappedAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute?view=netcore-3.1) excludes mapping of the denoted properties by the database.
This means the properties `Title` and `TitleArabic` will not get values if you read something from your database and only after you assign something manually.
If the table you're reading the data from got `Title` and `TitleArabic` columns you can just remove the NotMapped Attribute to fill these values when reading from your table.
Otherwise you can specify what these properties should return manually. For example:

```
public class DynamicClass
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string TitleArabic => GetArabicTitle(Title);
    public int? SeasonNumber { get; set; }
}
```

If you execute a query which wouldn't return `Title` or `ArabicTitle` the properties on the resulting object would just be null without the NotMapped Attribute.

Comment: The table itself actually not exist and thus columns also. when not mapped is removed everything working fine but everytime all column may not be return in the query

Comment: If I removed all the NotMapped property and query results doesn't contains all the coloumns i have given in model,then its causing error "Invalid Coloumn name""

Answer (score 0):

This is the idea of NotMapped Attribute which is ignoring these columns in Database mapping.

> Denotes that a property or class should be excluded from database mapping.

If you remove NotMapped attribute, You will always get the value of these columns. If they were null in the database, the mapped value will be also null.

Comment: If I removed all the NotMapped property and query results doesnt contains all the coloumns i have given in model,then its causing error "Invalid Coloumn name""

Comment: You can't "have your cake and eat it too", either all the columns are mapped and always in the result set, or they aren't. If you have multiple raw queries that return different results, you will need different result types.

Comment: the problem is iam generating this sql string dynanamically..
so all the fields in my model are not getting returned everytime in my query.
The error aim getting is :-
The required column 'Title' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation

Comment: Well, In this case, it depends on how much your sql query is dynamic. If you have only these 2 cases where you either have these 2 columns in the query or not, maybe you can separate your model class into 2 classes where one of them has these 2 columns [without the NotMapped attribute assigned to them] and the other class without these columns.